# Control Panel Themes

Tags: control-panel, cp-themes

What is the procedure for downloading and installing the alternative themes for ExpressioneEngine's Control Panel?

I've read in one of the books available on the topic that there are three additional Control Panel themes available: "Corporate", "Fruit" and "Mobile", but I can't find them.

Would be grateful for some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corporate is in my cp_themes folder in the 2.5.5 download, but Fruit & Mobile are not.

You should pose this question to EllisLab via their Support channel or in the Forums as I'm not seeing any way to access these under My Purchases on their site.

Answer (score 3):

There are several control panel themes made by third-party authors. The best place to find them is on [Devot-ee.com](http://devot-ee.com/). Just do a search for "[control panel theme](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=control%20panel%20theme&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2)."

Different themes may have slightly different installation instructions. Most of them follow these simple steps:

1. Copy the directory with the theme files to /themes/cp_themes
2. Place $config['cp_theme'] = '(theme_name)'; into your config.php file to ensure all users see the same theme

Personally, I've found the [Nerdery](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nerdery) theme to work quite well. It's very simple and minor tweaks, but looks more professional than the default (it's blue instead of pink) and works well with third-party add-ons. [Sassy-CP](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sassy-cp) is another good option. It has several color ways to choose from. Both are free.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen/heard of Fruit or Mobile either.  You can check out Devot-ee for other CP themes at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?t=cpt Personally, I like Nerdery and Sassy CP.

Basically, the new theme gets put into the "/themes/cp_themes" folder.  So in my case, I have the following folders:

- corporate
- default
- nerdery
- nostalgia
- sassy_cp

Each of the theme folders should have subfolders like css, images, etc. (could be js too).  So make sure that is the case, or else it won't work.

Comment: Fruit is a really old theme that EllisLab dropped. It was only in the beta and some very early 2.0 releases I think. It was ugly to say the least.